# Calling action from view JavaScript in mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, action, call

View JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
});
  });
```

I want to call controller action. source:[ call action ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From jQuery UI site http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote:

```
$( "input#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: "mysourceactionhere"
});
```

If your JS code on the view, you can use:

```
$( "input#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: '@Url.Action("SourceAction", "SourceController")'
});
```